# How to set rowspan and colspan values on gwt Grid cell containing a widget?

Tags: gwt, grid

let's say I have a code like this

```
Grid g = new Grid(2,2);
Label l = new Label("Hello");
g.setWidget(0,1, l);
s.setColspan(0,1,2); // there is no such method :(
```

So how can I set rowspan and colspan values on gwt Grid cell containing a widget?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If it's an option you can use [FlexTable](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlexTable.html) instead of Grid:

```
FlexTable flexTb= new FlexTable();
flexTb.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(0, 1, 2);
flexTb.setWidget(0, 1, new Label("Hello"));
```

Comment: Just FYI, `FlexTable` is slower than `Grid` (http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/BulkTableRenderers), so unless you have to dynamically add cells, you should stick with `Grid` for maximum performance :)

Comment: @Cataclysm "And question didn't say he has any options" As a Technical Manager you really should change your way of thinking. Also, feel free to offer "useful information".

Comment: sorry , question `How to set rowspan and colspan values on gwt Grid cell containing a widget?` . I assume this answer was not for it. FlexTable , there has build-in method to set colspan or rowspan but I also troubled to set spans in my GWT-DataGrid . Would you suggest me to use FlexTable ? No , it can't possible.

Comment: I'm sorry if this isn't a solution for you but you aren't the only reader on this website. It has obviously been helpful for a few others. So if in YOUR case you can't use flextable, please refer to other answers.

Comment: `/**
 * Sets the column span for the given cell. This is the number of logical
 * columns covered by the cell.
 * 
 * @param row the cell's row
 * @param column the cell's column
 * @param colSpan the cell's column span
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
 */`

Answer (score 8):

There is a not-so-simple-solution to this. It works by manipulating directly the DOM.

```
Grid g = new Grid(10, 5);

Element e = g.getCellFormatter().getElement(0, 0);
e.setAttribute("colspan", "5");

ArrayList<Element> toRemove = new ArrayList<Element>();
for (int x=1; x<5; x++)
    toRemove.add(g.getCellFormatter().getElement(0, x));
for (Element f : toRemove)
    f.removeFromParent();
```

It does following:

- set Attribute "colspan" of first TD to "5"
- remove other TDs in same row

Please note, that I used to for-loops. I tried it with one single loop but some of the elements were NULL, so I tried it this way and it worked.

Thomas

Comment: This does not work in IE 7,8, or 9.  Currently looking for the same solution for CellTable

Comment: I switched from trying to manipulate the dom to css-formating. There are nice things which can be done like

.my-table tr:first-child > td:first-child + td { border: none }

and something ... It would format the 2nd cell in the first row to have no border. So, I formatted my table to appear the way if  colspan was 5, for instance.